# Received data from socket and sort and display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I received data from socket and I need to live sort this data and display.
My code looke like this but only display unsort data.

```
$.each( data.players, function( key, value ) {
    var p = value.value[0]/1000;
    $('<tr>'+       
            '<td>'+
                    '<p class="price">$'+ p.toFixed(2)+'</p>'+
            '</td>'+
     '</tr>').appendTo('#target').hide().fadeIn(700);
});
```

Second problem:
When data was sorted and displayed and socket receive new player, it shoud be added on right place.

Data to sort (each object with id have price atrubute):
[data to sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkXB.png)

Comment: Where is the data that needs to be sorted? Show us sample data.

Comment: it would be helpful if you sent us some sample data @jensej2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```js
var data = {};

// simulate async data retrieval from socket 
setInterval(function() {
  // random data
  data[parseInt(getRandom(1, 10000))] = {};

  // update dome when new data is received
  updateDom();
}, getRandom(1000, 5000));

// call this method each time new data is received
updateDom();

function updateDom() {
  var keys = [];

  // add object keys to an array to be able to sort them
  for (k in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      keys.push(parseInt(k));
    }
  }

  keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    // sort values
    return (a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0);
  }).forEach(function(e) {
    if ($('#target [key=' + e + ']').length === 0) {
      // if we haven't printed this yet

      // generate dom
      var domE =
        '<tr key="' + e + '"><td>' +
        '<p class="price">$' + e + '</p>' +
        '</td></tr>';

      // get value of previous key
      var prevKey = keys.indexOf(e) - 1;
      prevKey = prevKey < 0 ? 0 : prevKey;

      // get previous element
      var keyBefore = $('#target [key=' + keys[prevKey] + ']');

      // if this does not have previous key exchange html
      if (keyBefore.length === 0) {
        $('#target').html(domE);
      } else {
        keyBefore
          .after(domE)
          .hide()
          .fadeIn(700);
      }
    }
  });
}

// utils - ignore for real implementation
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Data here!</div>
```

Comment: nice but what when socket receive new data like: {
      value: 674
    }

Comment: @jensej2 so data structure looks like the following? [{value: 1}, {value: 3}, {value: 856}, {value: 534}, {value: 1213} ]

Comment: no :( is not array but object. {{value: 1}, {value: 3}, {value: 856}, {value: 534}, {value: 1213} }

Comment: @jensej2 thats not a valid data structure in js

Comment: okej i will change to  an array. But it will be working when dom is loaded and socked receive new player?

Comment: @jensej2 I edited the code snippet. Check it out. When you get a new message from the socket just use "data.push" to push new data into the dataset.

Comment: I have problem beacuse I can;t change from object to array becase I need to have index like : 823: { }

Comment: @jensej2 check it out now. It now uses an object data structure which is then processed to extract the object keys and ordered.

Comment: ok thanks but what when I received data = { 21: {} }; 1 min after? It will be add to right place?

Comment: @jensej2 modified the code again to give an example of async data

Comment: is any possible to add only one new element after few minutes? Because now is generated all

Comment: Yes, but that would entail a much more complex script since you want them sorted which is out of the scope of StackOverflow. If you don't want them sorted that would be an easy change. @jensej2

Comment: @jensej2 I was really bored so I decided to implement it. I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @jensej2 if this worked please consider giving the answer an upvote because its pretty much out of the scope of the purpose of StackOverflow :)

Comment: perfect. Thanks very much!

Comment: is any other possible to get var prevKey = keys.indexOf(index) - 1; because I need to change keys array and now isn't number but array